# Casting an object to IEnumerable<T> where T is not known

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to play with Reflection and ran into the following situation.

In the following code, let's assume that the 'obj' can be of types `IEnumerable<>` or `ICollection<>` or `IList<>`.

I would like to cast this System.Object to `IEnumerable<>` always (as `ICollection<>` and `IList<>` inherit from `IEnumerable<>` anyway), so that i would like to enumerate over the collection and use reflection to write the individual items.

Motivation behind this is I am just trying to see if how would Serializers, in general, serialize data and so I am trying to simulate that situation in the hope to understand Reflection too.

I thought of casting the object to **non-generic IEnumerable**, but thought that this would cause unnecessary boxing of objects, when let's say the actual instance of `IEnumerable<int>`...am I thinking right?

```
private void WriteGenericCollection(object obj)
    {
        Type innerType = obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

        //Example: IEnumerable<int> or IEnumerable<Customer>
        Type generatedType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(innerType);

        //how could i enumerate over the individual items?
    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, since you don't know the actual type of the items until runtime, you don't need to use the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface; just use the non-generic one, `IEnumerable` (the generic one inherits from it):

```
private void WriteGenericCollection(object obj)
{
    IEnumerable enumerable = (IEnumerable)obj;
    foreach(object item in enumerable)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using IEnumerable due to boxing..example: in the case of IEnumerable<int>...I can try doing "obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]" to get the actual type...wondering if this can help in any way?

Comment: @KiranChalla, no, I don't see how it would help... Using the generic interface is useless if you can't know the item type statically. In your situation, the non-generic interface will serve you just as well

Comment: What if I want to call code that works with `IEnumerable<T>` like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is rife with misconceptions. Let's clear them up.

> In the following code, let's assume that the 'obj' can be of types
>   `IEnumerable<>` or `ICollection<>` or `IList<>`.

If that is true, and if you know the type of enumerable, a better way of writing the method would be

```
private void WriteGenericCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> obj)
{
    // ...
}
```

> I would like to downcast this System.Object to IEnumerable<> always
>   (as ICollection<> and IList<> inherit from IEnumerable<> anyway), so
>   that i would like to enumerate over the collection and use reflection
>   to write the individual items.

"Inherit" is not a correct term when talking about interfaces; it could also give you the wrong ideas. Interfaces are best thought of as *contracts*: when considering to implement an interface, you can only decide to implement it as the author intended or not implement it at all.

Some interfaces are supersets of other interfaces; their contracts say "implementors must do this in addition to whatever else *that* contract says". But there is never any sharing of implementation as is common in inheritance, because interfaces do not have any.

"Downcasting" is also not the correct term for what you are doing in that method. Downcasting means casting to a more derived class; there's also casting to an interface:

```
// Note: the method is still generic!
private void WriteGenericCollection<T>(object obj)
{
    var casted = (IEnumerable<T>)obj;
}
```

> I thought of downcasting the object to non-generic IEnumerable, but
>   thought that this would cause unnecessary boxing of objects, when
>   let's say the actual instance of IEnumerable...am I thinking right?

Boxing would occur *if and only if* the object was an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) (a numeric type, a `bool`, an `enum` or a `struct`). If the object implements `IEnumerable<T>` for some known `T` then you can simply cast it to that. If `T` is unknown then cast to non-generic `IEnumerable` and take the possible performance hit (there is no way around it in any case).

You would only need to use reflection if you know *nothing* about the object (in which case of course you also need to have a plan for objects that cannot be enumerated, otherwise why allow passing them to your method in the first place?).

Comment: Thanks Jon...In my case, i do not know the type T...as i mentioned i am trying to imagine how serializers serialize objects, so when they encounter a generic collection, what would they do...in my above scenario, the assumption is that the object is enumerable always to keep things simple for discussion here...

Comment: *"Inherit" is not a correct term when talking about interfaces*: I disagree; although classes don't inherit from interfaces (they implement them), interfaces can inherit from other interfaces (e.g. ICollection<T> inherits from IEnumerable<T>)