# How to Use Reflection to Access Non-Public List and Its Non-Public Elements

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to access the list elements within an array to get the "Message" strings, like so:

```
string msg0 = sender.SyncHelper.UploadSyncProgressList[0].Results.Exception.Message;
string msg1 = sender.SyncHelper.UploadSyncProgressList[1].Results.Exception.Message;
...
```

I am given the "sender" object (which is of type "object"). The rest (SyncHelper, UploadSyncProgressList, Results, Exception and Message) are all non-public. For these, their class types are also of non-public types (except for "Exception").

This [image](http://magicparcel.com/images/CaptureSO1.PNG) shows the visual representation of the problem.

I have managed to use reflection to get to the list variable "UploadSyncProgressList" with the following code, but am stuck on how to loop through the list elements to get the "Messages" string:

```
PropertyInfo syncHelperInfo = sender.GetType().GetProperty("SyncHelper", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
object syncHelper = syncHelperInfo.GetValue(sender, null);

PropertyInfo uploadProgressSyncListInfo = syncHelper.GetType().GetProperty("UploadSyncProgressList", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
object uploadProgressSyncList = uploadProgressSyncListInfo.GetValue(syncHelper, null);
```

How do I then loop through "uploadProgressSyncList" elements to get the "Message" strings?

I am doing this because I need to access the low-level network error messages which are hidden in the 3rd party library.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cast uploadProgressSyncList to IEnumerable?

Comment: Thanks Robert. I don't have the computer to try it now, but would it be something similar to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169188/casting-an-object-to-ienumerablet-where-t-is-not-known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options here.

as UploadSyncProgressList is type of `List<ESRI...EventArgs>` which implements the following collection interfaces

**Generic**

- `IList<T>`
- `IEnumerable<T>`
- `ICollection<T>`
- `IReadOnlyList<T>`
- `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`

**Non Generic**

- `IEnumerable`
- `ICollection`
- `IList`

so if the EventArgs in context is public then you can cast your result `uploadProgressSyncList` to any of the generic interface

eg

```
IList<ESRI...EventArgs> syncList = (IList<ESRI...EventArgs>)uploadProgressSyncList;
```

you can use any of the generic interface above which suits your needs

if the event arg type is not public then a non generic is your choice

```
IList syncList = (IList)uploadProgressSyncList;
```

using `IList` `IList<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` interface will help you to retrieve via indexes

eg

```
var arg1 = syncList[0];
```

for all of above you can iterate using foreach

eg

```
foreach(var arg in syncList)
{
    //your logic with arg
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Casting to a non-generic list worked.